# Copy an entire folder in a setup.py file

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, py2exe

I have a python application (mainly done using pyqt). I am using py2exe to create the executable, my setup.py looks like this

```
from distutils.core import setup import py2exe import os 
includes=["sqlite3","sip","PyQt4","PyQt4.QtGui","PyQt4.QtCore"]
excludes=[] 
packages=[] 
dll_excludes=['libgdk-win32-1.0-0.dll', 'libgobject-2.0-0.dll', 'tcl84.dll', 'tk84.dll']

setup(

      options={"py2exe": {"compressed": 2,
                          "optimize": 2,
                          "includes": includes,
                          "excludes": excludes,
                          "packages": packages,
                          "dll_excludes": dll_excludes,
                          "bundle_files": 2,
                          "dist_dir": "dist",
                          "xref": False,
                          "skip_archive": False,
                          "ascii": False,
                          "custom_boot_script": '',
                          }
               },
      windows=['myapplication.py'],
      data_files = [('', [r'c:\configuration.ini',
                          r'c:readme.txt'
                          ])]

      )
```

Now the data_files entry allows me to copy a few files to the 'dist' folder, however I would also like to copy my documentation folder, the documentation folder includes a whole bunch of files, html,images,pdfs, about 2MB of documentation stored in a my_app\docs folder. I am not sure how to do this. Can anyone suggest how?

Comment: Take a look at the `shutil`-package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to use a custom function to do this as part of your `setup.py`:

```
def copy_dir():
    dir_path = 'YOUR_DIR_HERE'
    base_dir = os.path.join('MODULE_DIR_HERE', dir_path)
    for (dirpath, dirnames, files) in os.walk(base_dir):
        for f in files:
            yield os.path.join(dirpath.split('/', 1)[1], f)
```

Then I set this as my `package_data`:

```
package_data = {
    '' : [f for f in copy_dir()]
},
```

Note that this should also work if you're using `data_files`. Make sure that you call the function as part of a list comprehension - apparently setuptools doesn't play nice with list-alikes instead of straight up lists.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. could you also kindly explain how  we can specify the Python's `lib` directory and copy some libs that are needed by our extensions ?

Comment: I used `data_files` in the `setup()` like his : ```setup( ..., data_files=[ (python_lib_dir, libs_list),] ) ```